# Why doesn't sandboxing stop my app from accessing arbitrary URLs?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

My understanding is that a sandboxed app is disallowed from accessing arbitrary URLs not chosen by the user. Why, then, is my simple test app able to:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Library/Application Support/App Store/adoption.plist"))
```

Debug and Release builds both work, with no Console messages. My entitlements file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I must be misunderstanding something. Are a developer's apps unchecked on the development Mac? If so, how can I test that my app doesn't contain violations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using NSWorkspace you're not actually opening the file. Your app does not have access to the contents of that file.

You're just instructing the system to open that file with whatever is the default application that handles it. This is perfectly legal for sandboxed apps.

Try opening using NSFileHandle for example, and you should see an error.